# create a full featured product in blender using only the python language

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, sculpting, color-management

Modeling polygons in blender using mouse and keyboard is relatively easy, but it takes a a lot of time. I would like to know if I can sculpt/model/texture/paint/move/animate objects in blender using only the python language with a lower interaction with the mouse. Do you have some kind of how to and tutorials? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to be more specific because the tools in blender should be sufficient without having to know python.

That being said there is nothing you cannot do in blender using python.

If you drag down the top bar of blender (the line slightly below "File", "Render" etc), you will notice it reveals a window.

Do some actions in blender, and you will see their equivalent python commands. Use these to get started. Good luck!

Comment: Not true: there are couple things you **can't** do with python, because custom data of operators or events is not (fully) exposed to python. Examples: tablet pressure is not exposed (or was, I believe it is since this week), TIMER events don't tell you which timer fired the event, knife cut operator relies on custom data which you can't pass to the operator (there are bmesh ops for this however, but it's usually no high level API), emulate brush strokes (you can't fake events)...

Comment: Hello. For me it's very useful to learn how to use python to create an animation from start to finish. Do you have some kind of tutorial ?

Comment: @CoDEmanX LIES! You can do all of those things. For example, you could include a screen grab from an external python library. Then do some OpenCV, parse out the screen grab, and determine the state of the application. Sure it would be slow. However there is one thing that python can't do, and that is import curly braces. You have to use an external C library.

Comment: I was talking about Blender Python API, not what could be a theoretical workaround, and come on, screen grabbing and OpenCV is not very realistic, nor determistic. Braces are no problem however: https://www.python.org/doc/humor/#python-block-delimited-notation-parsing-explained | http://www.pythonb.org/

Comment: "there is nothing you cannot do in blender using python." Can you build a physical house? :P (I know you mean  "there's nothing you can do in Blender that you can't do with Python")

Comment: No I mean what I said. You can 3d print the house... next question?

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to use Python to enhance or automate mesh design, it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with what already exists and start learning the API only if nothing meets your needs.

Blender has a lot of great add-ons already available, and the Blender API is not the easiest thing to learn.  It's not unapproachable!  Don't be discouraged.  Just don't spend time on it unless you really need to because it's an investment. While you're programming, you probably won't be making art, and there's no way for you to know ahead of time how long that will take as you learn.

If you're looking to fully automate the creation of meshes, then unless everything you plan on creating can be described entirely with math and logic, you won't do it.  Think about that carefully because unless you are familiar with advanced math (trigonometry, calculus, linear algebra, differential equations), you will probably find that your add-on's capabilities will be very specific and limited.

On the other hand, if you have an idea for a way that your computer can help you to make meshes yourself (a tool, an operation on faces, edges, vertices, loops, UV, textures, etc) then it may be worth your while to learn the part of the API that you need.  There's really no reason to become proficient with everything in the API unless you plan on offering your services to develop plugins for others.

Remember, your computer is only a calculator.

Comment: user2813810 : I think that I've understood your point. But what to say about HTML 5 + WebGL, then ? I see that with these languages can be reached good results doing 3D animations. Using this way what's the most important part to learn ? programming or the artistic one ?

Comment: Which is more important depends upon the specific use case, so that's a meaningless question in the general sense.  Modelling expediency grows with experience, so if a person's goal is to make art and they have little experience, then their best choice is to practice.  There are already parametric modelling tools available, so it only makes sense to make a new one if there is a specific programming goal in mind.  The question pertains to using Blender for art, therefore it does not pertain to a specific programming goal.